# Can I use a reference DE for dynamic content in an Email that's being sent in a Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, lookup

I have a query in an automation that pulls a certain list of subscribers and creates Boolean values for an enrollment program - to be used in an email (i.e if x is true show x content). This query also populates subscriber ID and Email and runs every hour in Marketing Cloud. The query is pulling from a synchronized Data Extension in Marketing Cloud.
The journey is using an enrollment record activity to enter subscribers in the journey. All of the subscribers have at least 1 enrollment program.

Can I use a lookup in that email to look at the Ref Data Extension?
If so, how do I compare the email address in the Ref Data extension to the email address being sent to in the journey?

Answer (score 0):

You can use personalization string `%%emailaddr%%` in you email and perform a lookup in the table and fetch the details. This string will give you the email address of the subscriber in context of sending